# ¿Como Usar El Api De Google Drive En Eclipse?

Tags: android

He estado tratando de usar la api de Google Drive en eclipse pero no sale un contenido actualizado de como hacerlo si sabe como lo puede hacer por favor ayuda.

Comment: Cual es tu código o donde tienes problemas?

Comment: El problema es no se como importo esa librería que se menciona en los tutoriales antiguos que se importa como proyecto en eclipse cuyo nombre creo que es  "libs"  porque a mi al descargar google play service desde el sdk me crea las carpetas doc y example nada mas no eso que te acabo de mencionar.

Comment: Pregunta muy abierta, fuera de todo eso recomiendo que te mudes a Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente no deberías usar Eclipse para desarrollar en Android Studio porque no es la IDE oficial y porque seguramente te encontraras problemas porque el plugin no ha sido actualizado.

- [Tienes que crear un proyecto y habilitar la API.](https://console.developers.google.com//start/api?id=drive&credential=client_key)
- [Tienes que obtener tu SHA-1 del Keystore que estes usando para firmar la aplicación](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started)

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started

Después de configurar tu proyecto aquí tienes un [ejemplo básico](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java), trata de realizarlo y pregunta si tienes dudas más especificas.

Comment: Esto que me acabas de entregar o ayudar sirve para eclipse verdad y muchas gracias por responder.